# Generate point to point routes (Fiber Network not FTTH/P)

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS. I have a pre-existing network which I have imported into QGIS showing lines (Fiber) and points (Nodes). I am trying to put a system in place to automatically generate routes using my existing network.

At the moment I just want to generate point to point routes using my Network as the roadmap and to set up the conditions on how it routes between sites, considering each cable goes to a specific node.

Example. Cable 1 going from Node A to B (Shown in picture), then cable 2 going from Node B to c. If I trace this cable it takes the shortest path possible (Node A to C). What I am trying to achieve is when I trace this cable that it will follow Node A to Node B then to Node C.

[image: Node A bottom left Node B bottom Right Node c Top Right]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: FiberPlanIT https://comsof.com/fiber uses QGIS with postgis backend here is an older version qgis > https://youtu.be/8Q5zugVfNsM?t=1253

Comment: Currently, I have found nothing of use. I have been previously been using Mapinfo so QGIS is completely new to me. I have updated my original post with a bit more context.

Comment: You find interesting network analysis methods in GRASS GIS: see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_network_analysis and https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/wxGUI.vnet.html

Comment: In your toolbox there is the category "network analysis", there is a method called "shortest path". It's either point to layer or layer to point or point to point. This will only work if there are nodes where to lines are splitting up and all lines have to be connected

Comment: FTTP is not based on shortest path - ideally full redundancy is another independent separate loop.